# NightwatchJS: Custom Command not failing on error

Tags: nightwatch.js

Here is my custom command:

```
exports.command = function (element, time, debug) {
  let waitTime = time || 10000
  if (debug) {
    return this
      .log('waiting ' + waitTime + 'ms for: ' + element)
      .waitForElementVisible(element, waitTime)
  }
  return this
    .waitForElementVisible(element, waitTime)
}
```

I have also set this variable in the **globalModules**: `abortOnFailure: true`.

When I call this in a pageObject though like this:

```
findElement() {
   this.waitFor('#driversLicenseNumbers');
   return this
}
```

The object isn't found (which is *expected* and *intended* since I'm upgrading to Nightwatch v1.0.14) and the error message is logged to the console, but the test doesn't fail.

> × Timed out while waiting for element <#driversLicenseNumbers> to be
>   present for 10000 milliseconds. - expected "visible" but got: "not
>   found"

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey! Did you get to downgrade WDIO to a working version? Let me know if you wanna further debug...

Comment: I had to remove the npm audit script from our travis.yml to skip due to several critical and high vulnerabilities that at currently in the 0.9.x nightwatch version we currently have.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an open issue on the [Nightwatch issues board](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues) regarding this specific problem.  **[Here](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1941)** it is!

This behavior affects `custom_commands` in `nightwatch@1.0.15` & `nightwatch@0.9.21` (*according to the BUG report*, yet I am running `nightwatch@0.9.21` & this behavior is not reproducible for me).

Basically your test fails, but it does so **silently**, at the end of the test, where you get the timeout error.

**Proposed fix:** Install a different version (`npm install --save-dev nightwatch@0.9.x`), or a suitable version that hasn't introduced the defect yet.

Cheers!